# How can I customize the tooltip position in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I created a simple QWidget and set a tooltip using the `setToolTip()` function. The tooltip works, but I would like to manually specify its position for display. Is there any way to achieve this?

This is my code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *



class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(1920, 1080)
        self.showMaximized()

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.widget.setFixedHeight(500)
        self.widget.setVisible(True)
        self.widget.setToolTip('Tooltip')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There are a lot of things to consider when positioning a tooltip. it is tricky to keep it from going off screen, but needs to be close to the element, but not cover the element if possible...

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Actually, Qt already ensures that the tool tip is *always* within the screen geometry (except for the rare cases for which the tool tip is actually wider or taller than the screen resolution).

Comment: Can you clarify what do you need this for? Maybe you want only a *specific* area of the widget that shows a tool tip when hovered?

Comment: [As stated in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop), you need to use [an event-filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) to watch for ToolTip events and then use [QToolTip.showText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText) to customise the behaviour.

Comment: @musicamante No, what I want is to be able to manually set the tooltip position, e.g. offsetting it by a certain amount. I'd like it to be drawn at a different position.

Comment: @musicamante yeah, that's my point. Trying to manipulate that will only break it

Comment: @Marco Well, the fact is that the tool tip is *never* placed exactly at the given position: that is used as a *reference*, then Qt computes a possibly valid position considering the cursor size and adapting to the screen DPI so that it will be (normally) shown at its bottom right, and *then* adjusts the position considering the screen geometry, which means that it might be even shown on the top right of the given position. So, there's no direct way to directly place the QToolTip at a specific position, *unless* you install an application wide event filter in order to check top level windows.